# Laravel Nova - Can a field dependsOn parent resource field with-in a HasOne relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

The parent resource has these fields

```
    Select::make('Currency')->options(...),
    HasOne::make('Child', 'child', 'App\Nova\ChildResource')->required(),
```

as I've added HasOne->required, the child resource field are displayed inline (on the same page) while I create (Add new) parent resource. The child fields are as follows:

```
    Text::make('Some Field')
       ->dependsOn(['???'], function() {})   //it depends upon Currency Field in the parent resource
```

I want to know if this is possible? if yes then what attribute I should mention instead of ??? in dependsOn?

I've tried using 'currency', but it does not work...

Answer (score 0):

The other end of the HasOne relationship is a Child's parent function that returns a belongsTo.

```
function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Parent::class);
}
```

add the relationship in nova

```
BelongsTo::make('Parent'),
```

and then you can use depends

```
Text::make('Some Field')->dependsOn(['parent'], 
    function (Text $field, NovaRequest $request, FormData $formData) {
        $model = $request->findModel();
        if ($model && $model->parent && $model->parent->currency === 'USD') 
        {
            $field->readonly(true);
        }
    }
),
```